# sampled machines when using queues

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to Amazon Web Services and am currently trying to get my head around how Simple Queue Service (SQS) works.

In the link [ReceiveMessage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/Query_QueryReceiveMessage.html) the following is mentioned:

> Short poll is the default behavior where a weighted random set of
>   machines is sampled on a ReceiveMessage call. This means only the
>   messages on the sampled machines are returned. If the number of
>   messages in the queue is small (less than 1000), it is likely you will
>   get fewer messages than you requested per ReceiveMessage call. If the
>   number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you might not
>   receive any messages in a particular ReceiveMessage response; in which
>   case you should repeat the request.

What I understand there is one queue and many machines/instances can read the messages. What is not clear to me is what does "weighted random set of  machines" means? Is there more than one queue on a number of machines? Clearly I am lacking some knowledge on on SQS works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what this means is that because SQS is geographically distributed, not all of the machines (amazon's servers that have your queue) will have the exact same queue content at all times because they won't always be in sync with each other at every instant.

You don't know or control from which of amazons servers it will serve messages from, it uses an algorithm to figure out which messages are sent to you when you request some. That is why you don't always get messages when you ask for them, and occasionally the same message will get served up more than once; you need to make sure whatever your processing entails it can deal with the possibility that it is processing something that has already been processed by another of your worker machines.

Comment: Thank you so much. I some how associated the queue with instances rather than think about geographical Amazon servers that have queues.:).